# Postman script for setNextRequest does not work

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using a sample from https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/.

My request is named "MyTestRequest." It is a POST request. In the "Tests" tab of the request, I have the following code:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
  postman.setNextRequest("MyTestRequest");
  console.log("Iteration:" + i);
  i++;
}
```

When I click on the Send button, I should be seeing four POST requests. The first POST happens even before the above code gets executed.

However, I see only one POST request. Although I do see three console log lines, it appears setNextRequest is not doing anything.

My code is no different than the example in the document. Wondering if anyone has any insight. Thanks.

Comment: The `sendNextRequest` only works with the Collection Runner and not individual requests.

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/#setnextrequest-only-works-in-collection-runner